# Oracle SQL - Reusing column from the first table on LEFT JOIN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Please consider the following db<>fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8d3223f66c3f88294f84645756420836

I have a (simplified) table named `sample_data` that looks like this:

```
key         values      separator   fields
--------------------------------------------------------
10791701    16;20;      ;           FIELD1;FIELD2
10791702    17|18|19|   |           FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5
```

What I'd like to do here is to perform a query whose output would be this:

```
key         value       field
--------------------------------------------------------
10791701    16          FIELD1
10791701    20          FIELD2
10791702    17          FIELD3
10791702    18          FIELD4
10791702    19          FIELD5
```

That is, I'd like to, somehow, split the values in the `values` column and assign them the corresponding field name in the `fields` column.

Here's what I've tried:

```
select *
  from sample_data t1
  left join (select t1.key, column_value from table(apex_string.split(t1.fields, t1.separator))) t2
    on t1.key = t2.key;
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, because Oracle displays: `ORA-00904: "T1"."FIELDS": invalid identifier`. It would seem to me that, when using the `left join` clause, it won't allow me to use columns from the `t1` alias above.

How, then, do I obtain the desired output?

Comment: Use `left join lateral` instead.

Comment: My apologies. I should've mentioned that I'm working with Oracle 11g here. IIRC, `left join lateral` is only available from Oracle 12, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by using a sort of a "divide and conquer" strategy. Here's how it goes:

```
create table SAMPLE_DATA
(
  key        VARCHAR2(8),
  the_values VARCHAR2(10),
  separator  VARCHAR2(1),
  the_fields VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Then I insert the data like so:

```
insert into sample_data (KEY, THE_VALUES, SEPARATOR, THE_FIELDS)
values ('10791701', '16;20;', ';', 'FIELD1;FIELD2');

insert into sample_data (KEY, THE_VALUES, SEPARATOR, THE_FIELDS)
values ('10791702', '18|17|19|', '|', 'FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5');

insert into sample_data (KEY, THE_VALUES, SEPARATOR, THE_FIELDS)
values ('10791703', '77,99,88', ',', 'FIELD6,FIELD7,FIELD8');
```

Then, finally, use the following query:

```
with t1 as
 (select * from sample_data),
t2 as
 (select key, row_number() over(partition by key order by null) value_index, column_value
    from t1, table(apex_string.split(the_values, separator))
   where column_value is not null),
t3 as
 (select key, row_number() over(partition by key order by null) value_index, column_value
    from t1, table(apex_string.split(the_fields, separator))
   where column_value is not null)
select t1.key, t2.column_value the_value, t3.column_value the_field
  from t1
  left join t2
    on t1.key = t2.key
  left join t3
    on t2.key = t3.key
   and t2.value_index = t3.value_index;
```

## Output

```
KEY         THE_VALUE   THE_FIELD
---------------------------------
10791701    16          FIELD1
10791701    20          FIELD2
10791702    18          FIELD3
10791702    17          FIELD4
10791702    19          FIELD5
10791703    77          FIELD6
10791703    99          FIELD7
10791703    88          FIELD8
```

## Explanation

Basically, tables `t2` and `t3` split the `the_values` and `the_fields` columns while also retrieving the 1-based indexes (`row_number() over(partition by key order by null)`) for each split that occurs. All that's left then is to join the relation table and the other two.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `lateral` clause in 11g, however the relation from `table` function can be joined using plain old comma notation.

In your case the problem IMHO is you declared `"fields"` as quoted identifier so you have to quote it in query too.

So final solution could look like

```sql
select *
  from sample_data t1,
  table(apex_string.split(t1."fields", t1."separator")) t2
```

(Not verified in db fiddle - apex function is not supported there.)

Comment: The issue is the `t1`, not the quoted identifiers.  This should not work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I admit it's counterintuitive though it works, I ocassionally use it (and verified on my docker with apex function emulation, dbfiddle has limitations). Also the quoted idents. Seems OP successfully applied both my tips in his solution :-D